# preAuthorize annotation doesn't seem to work

Tags: spring-security, spring-aop

We are trying to put method level security using Spring's @preAuthorize tags. Everything compiles and runs fine but the restrictions don't happen. This is an admin only method but even non-admins can access. Here is how we've configured it in the context:

```xml
<http use-expressions="true" create-session="never"  entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" authentication-manager-ref="authManager">
    <intercept-url pattern="/mocks/some-service" access="hasRole('ROLE_OTHER')" />
    <form-login authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp" default-target-url="/login.jsp" login-page="/login.jsp"></form-login>
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER" />

  </http>

<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
```

And here is the method itself:

```java
@PreAuthorize("(hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN'))")
public Some doIt(Some Input) {
            do something;
    return some;
}
```

But everyone can have a piece of something. What am I missing? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turned out that you can not have annotations on methods that are accessed from within the same class, whether private or public. The annotations only work on public methods accessed by outsiders.

Hope that helps someone making the same mistake.

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context This link advices securing service layer methods. They are frequently used by other private/public methods.

Comment: indeed it does! I had PreAuthorize on the first method called which fired correctly, then when that method called another secured method in the same class is didn't. Spent ages going through various handlers and evaluators, and this was all it was....

Comment: thanks for `only work on public methods`, what's misleading is that the method is registered to handle requests but protected only if public.

Answer (score 6):

Please take a look at this: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context

To sum up:

> "You need to either move the  declaration to
>   the web context or moved the beans you want secured into the main
>   application context."